# Javascript detect control key held on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've searched a good deal, and can't seem to find a satisfactory solution.  I hope someone can help.

While I am using jQuery, I am also writing many thousands of lines of JavaScript.  So a "pure" JavaScript solution is just fine.

I'm trying to determine if the control key is physically held down on a `mouseup` event.  That's it; there are no other preconditions.  Does anyone know how to do this reliably, cross-browser?

I've tried storing this in a state variable by noting when the key is pressed and released:

```
// BEGIN store control key status in hash_state
$().bind('keydown','ctrl',function( arg_obj_e ){
  hash_state.sw_ctrldn = true;
  console.debug( hash_state.sw_ctrldn );
});
$().bind('keyup','ctrl',function( arg_obj_e ){
  hash_state.sw_ctrldn = false;
  console.debug( hash_state.sw_ctrldn );
});
// END store control key status in hash_state
```

However, this really doesn't work.  If you test this using Firebug and watch the console, you will see that auto-repeat seems to happen, and the value toggles.

I inspected the `mouseup` event to see if there is anything useful there, but to no avail:

```
var debugEvent = function( arg_obj_e ){
  var str = '';
  for ( var attr in arg_obj_e ){
    str += attr + ': ' + arg_obj_e[attr] + '\n';
  }
  console.debug(str);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know jQuery supported key events that way. I can't find any documentation of it. Also, does $().bind() (empty jQuery) work, or is that just shorthand? If so, is it bound to $(document)?

Comment: @eyelidlessness: That kind of binding is from a plugin called js-hotkeys http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/

Comment: This also won't work because if the user does control+F to search the page, the find window has focus when they let go of control, so no keyup for control (nor F) fire. Also if you need to track the F key then you'll think it's down forever after that and I don't have a solution for that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the [event.ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.ctrlKey) property.

```
$(function(){
  $('#elementId').mouseup(function(e){
    var isCtrlPressed = e.ctrlKey;
    // true or false whether ctrl is pressed or not 
  });
});
```

Check a running example [here](http://jsbin.com/okehu/edit).

Comment: Wow, I was looking for that property during the event debug, and must have missed it.  Thank you!  Works like a charm on FF3; now to see about IE.

Comment: You're welcome Michael, these key modifiers (shiftKey, ctrlKey, altKey) were introduced on the *DOM Level 2* standard (http://is.gd/1Vryp) in the late year 2000, and is supported since IE6.

Comment: Even better!  I want to use both shiftKey and altKey in my app as well.  I just found that ctrl-mousewheel in firefox defaults to text zooming, which could case my users fits.  Maybe better to use one of the other keys :)

These properties must "spring to life" when queried, it seems, because just iterating over the attributes of the event object gave me nothing, IIRC.

Again, thanks a lot.  Saved e much trouble.

Comment: The properties are probably in the prototype chain