# selecting gridview rows using ctrl key

Tags: asp.net

I need help for selecting multiple rows in a gridview using ctrl key. (C#, asp.net)

While right clicking on the selected rows, I need to export those particular rows to "word".

Comment: i need without using checkbox.... please help

Answer (score 1):

Although the easier way to do this is placing the checkbox at the starting of rows and then using checked boxes for exporting rows. you can look at following link:

[Javascript Detect Control Key Held on Mouseup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210547/javascript-detect-control-key-held-on-mouseup)

Comment: did you checked the link I placed in answer? that is without using checkbox, i.e. tracking key host mouse up js event, check if that helps